# Using universal load data on server in Sveltekit

Tags: sveltekit

I am in a situation where my list of contacts gets loaded in on initial load through layout.ts universal file which is accessible throughout the client using page data.

I use this contact data to derive contact ids to select on the client/front end, send the ids back to the server on a form submit, but now I need to get additional contact data on the server that was available on initial universal load.

Other than stuffing a form input as a string with loads of contact data and sending it back to the server,or caching the database and doing a second database call, there has to be an easier way to access data that was already loaded.

What options do I have?

I assume that the universal load data should be accessible on the server to avoid duplicate database calls.

Comment: Two thoughts: 1.) no client-side page data: keep all of your data on the server side and simply always request from server. This is the most common client-server setup. 2.) You could concatenate the client-side data with the data returned by the server call (if your use case fits this situation). For more help, please provide more motivation for your setup, what the server call is doing, etc.